# How can I modify the existing email CSV script to skip blank rows, or rows with a single zero in either field?

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script

I've been using the Google-provided script to generate and email CSVs from Google Sheets. I customised it so that it doesn't ask for a range or a file name. This way it just automatically emails me, periodically, with the contents of my range.

The problem is that the CSV contains empty rows, at the end, that I'd like the script to automatically filter out (which I can't achieve, because I just don't have the knowledge). The reason for this, in turn, is that the *range* contains empty rows - but there's a good reason for that, which is that the rows in the range sometimes expand, sometimes contract, depending on the underlying data. (The range in fact relates to a pivot table).

As a bonus prize, I'd also really like it to skip rows, if there is a single zero in either of the two columns in the rows. (I ought to be able to filter this out in the pivot table; I can, but then the filters don't work properly if new values appear).

This is an example of how my emailed CSVs are looking at the moment:

```
0,0
,0
0.65,0
0.75,16900
0.78,2000
0.79,500
0.8,110800
0.83,1200
0.85,20000
0.87,4500
0.9,3500
1,5000
1.1,4000
1.2,41500
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
```

This is an example of how I would like to receive that CSV:

```
0.75,16900
0.78,2000
0.79,500
0.8,110800
0.83,1200
0.85,20000
0.87,4500
0.9,3500
1,5000
1.1,4000
1.2,41500
```

Any help with this would be HUGELY appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the script I'm using currently:

```
var settings = {
  "recipients": "myemailaddress",
  "emailSubject": "CSV file",
  "emailMessage": "Your CSV file is attached",
  "fileExtension": ".csv",
  "carriageReturn": "\r\n"
};

function onOpen() {
  var subMenus = [];
  subMenus.push({name: "Email Named Range as CSV", functionName: "run"});
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("CSV", subMenus);
}

function run() {
  /var namedRange = Browser.inputBox("Enter named range to convert to CSV (e.g. sampleDataRange):");/
  var namedRange = "FORCSVEXPORT";
  var fileName = "EPCSELLOFFERS.CSV";

  if (namedRange.length !== 0 && fileName.length !== 0) {  
    settings.dataRangeName = namedRange;
    settings.csvFileName = fileName + settings.fileExtension;
    var csvFile = convertNamedRangeToCsvFile_(settings.dataRangeName, settings.csvFileName);
    emailCSV_(csvFile);
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Please enter a named range and a CSV file name.");
  }
}

function emailCSV_(csvFile) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(settings.recipients, settings.emailSubject, settings.emailMessage, {attachments: csvFile});
}

function convertNamedRangeToCsvFile_(rngName, csvFileName) {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(rngName);
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row += 1) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col += 1) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // Join each rows columns
        // Add carriage return to end of each row
        csv += data[row].join(",") + settings.carriageReturn;
      }
      csvFile = [{fileName: csvFileName, content: csv}];
    } 
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the source data in your `FORCSVEXPORT` range look like?

Comment: And where did you get the original script from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hack the original `convertNamedRangeToCsvFile_()`, I propose adding an additional step to your `run()`, that will call a new function to remove the unwanted rows from the csv file. Here it is:

```
/**
 * Remove unwanted lines from given csvFile
 */
function minimizeCsvFile( csvFile ) {
  // take apart the csv file contents, into an array of rows
  var rows = csvFile[0].content.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");
  var newRows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
    if (rows[i] == "") continue;   // skip blanks
    if (rows[i] == ",") continue;  // skip null values
    // skip rows with either numeric value == 0
    var vals = rows[i].split(",");
    if (parseFloat(vals[0]) == 0.0 || parseFloat(vals[1]) == 0.0) continue;
    // If we got here, we have a keeper - add it to newRows
    newRows.push(rows[i]);
  }
  debugger;   // pause to observe in debugger
  var csv = newRows.join(settings.carriageReturn);
  // Return a single element array with an object, exactly like
  // the one from convertNamedRangeToCsvFile_.
  return [{fileName: csvFile[0].fileName, content: csv}];
}
```

To make use of it, change the `emailCSV_()` line in `run()` to:

```
var minimizedCsvFile = minimizeCsvFile(csvFile);
emailCSV_(minimizedCsvFile);
```

And as for this...

> As a bonus prize... Any help with this would be HUGELY appreciated. Thanks.

All we ever want here is for new members of StackOverflow to acknowledge when they receive help! Have a look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/206345) for tips on how to accept answers. (You can build rep by asking, answering and accepting answers!)

But I've always wanted a Ferrari...

Comment: well, if I had a ferrari I'd share it with pleasure but I don't ;-/ in the meantime, +1 for clarity as usual !

Comment: This is brilliant, Mogsdad, thanks - but I can't quite make it work! I get this error message:

Comment: @PhilipRead - What's the error message? But also, see the comments I posted earlier about your source data. Since you never said what it looked like, I guessed you had two columns of numbers.

Comment: OK: sorry about the wierd half post; this appears to work terrifically.

You say that you want people to acknowledge when they receive help: well, I can certainly do that! This is really a massive help for a task I was trying to complete. Thank you SO much Mogsdad. (this is for you by the way: it's a MOG Ferrari: http://www.renaissance-models.com/images/Protos_Etienne/123_MOG_Ferrari_Mythos.jpg)

Comment: @PhilipRead - hehe! That wouldn't take up much room in my driveway!